# is it possible that all supportive packages to be downloaded before starting automation suites in python?

Tags: python

I am designing automation suite in python. So currently entire automation suites have been developed in centos environment which already have some very basic python packages. and during development of automation suites whichever packages required i downloaded them using pip or easy_install utility.But my major concern is that if this suites will be deployed in different environment in may fail because some of packages will not be present there. 
so what i am planning to build a shell script which picks package name and URL from property file and download all required packages from internet. 
But i just wanted to ensure that, is there any utility available which automatically detect additional packages from automation suites and downloaded them directly from internet?

Thanks,

Priyank Shah

Comment: what packages do you want to use? plain c or c++ with python? if `c` or `c++` then may want to build `*.so`libs from sources.

Comment: it is mainly about python packages paramiko,cx_oracle xml parsing etc..

Comment: it's packages available from `pip`?

Comment: yes most of packages are available from pip except cx_oracle (to be installed using setup.py).

Comment: for `cx_oracle` you could write own distribution package. http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/